# Callout MapView Android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, overlayitem

Is it possible to have a callout attached to an ItemizedOverlay item like in the iPhone and Google maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with 'Callout' you mean the info window / 'balloon tip' that appears usually? Here's code and sample:

http://deckjockey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-baloon-display-on-map.html